# How can I increase the timer count ( CountDownTimer )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I'm planning to increase the number of seconds by 5 seconds when I reach a number of clicks of let's say 30 clicks , then increase the seconds by other 5 when i reach 60 clicks and so on.

please help with this problem

```
public class game extends linear_layout {
LinearLayout b1;
TextView t1;
int num=0;
TextView timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gamelayout);
    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    b1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int x = 10000;
            num = num + 1;
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(num));


            new CountDownTimer(x, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                }

                public void onFinish() {

                    Intent i1 = new Intent(game.this, linear_layout.class);
                    startActivity(i1);
                    finish();
                }

         }
                    .start();
        }  }); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the number of seconds of a CountDownTimer, instead when you want to increase it, you just cancel the previous one and create a new CountDownTimer with the new value.

Few things to note:

Don't do `new CountDownTimer` in an anonymous way, you do need a reference to the CountDownTimer so you'll be able to stop it when updating is needed.

Another thing is that you can't cancel a CountDownTimer from whithin its methods, so if you want to cancel the previous timer and create the new CountDownTimer from the onTick, you should use an alternative like [CountDownTimer alternative](https://gist.github.com/Gautier/737759)

Comment: is it possible to tell me where to indicate the new CountDownTimer? , Im still a beginner lol

Comment: It's up to the logic of your app, if you'll explain a bit more, I will try to help.

Comment: its about clicking .. there will be a high score and if i would click more than the high score the time will increase by 5 seconds , thats it